# Use image as multiple buttons in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I want to use the below image as a five different buttons. In addition, the image must stay at the bottom of the screen. Any ideas on how can I accomplish this?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use just one image, it is possible but harder and it is not the best option because you have to take care of the size according to the devices. But as I said, it is not impossible. You have to detect where the finger did the tap and then, with some maths, decided which "button" was touched.

To detect the tap, you can use "[onTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html)" or use a "[GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html)".

Comment: well, I can try to guide you. First, in your layout, use **relative-layout** and set the image at the bottom. Remember to give an ID to the image.In your activity, get the image and set **onTouchListener** to it. Also you should get the dimensions of the screen and the dimension of your image, so you can now the range. For example, if your screenHeight is 240 and your image is 40, when a touch event occurs, check if the coordinate y is in your range (top: 200, bottom 240). In that case, the user touched the image. Now, do the same in the coordinate x and you will get the button.

Answer (score 1):

That wouldn't work. The best choice would be to split up the images, and use them separately.

You will probably have to have separate images for the dividers as well.

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
 tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
           Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, javaclass.class);
        TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
        ImageView img1 = new ImageView(this);
            img1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(tabWidth, tabHeight));
        img1.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            tab1.setIndicator(img1).setContent(intent1);
```

and set image as background on xml Layout as below

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layTab"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/image"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            >
            <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [ImageButtons](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) and define your background.
As for splitting up I am unsure but I guess it is always possible to have 1 for each "button" and just align them neatly.

Answer (score 0):

yap, You can use tabSpec as above and then split this images and set to each tabSpec and add this tabSpec into tabHost and set backGround to black its look like this.